# MacBook Pro Failed to join Network

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

I cannot connect to wifi with my Mac. It happened before and i asked about it in this post: [Macbook pro does not connect wifi](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125803/macbook-pro-does-not-connect-wifi)

This time when i follow steps in there, it gives me this error:
Failed to join network myNetworkName..
Error:-3905 Timeout error

Comment: seriously guys, still no answer? :s

Comment: it is the incorrect network name, check it again